# Backbone.js as hybrid approach with jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, backbone.js, menu

Suppose there are 5 menu items on page.
Menu of 5 items

---

```
                   Discussion -load using Backbone.js
                   Connection -load using Backbone.js
                   Planning -load using Backbone.js
                   Management -load using Backbone.js
                   Workflow -load using JSP Page
```

---

Last one is to be loaded using jsp page.
Can backbone.js framework be used as hybrid approach where some pages are in backbone and some pages are in traditional jsp pages?If yes how can this be achieved?